# php variable not loading image correctly

Tags: php, mysql, html

I seem to be having some difficulty with loading images in my website.
I wrote some basic code to test to see if it was my original code and it seems to be doing the exact same thing. 
Lets say for example -

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){

  $img = $row["image_thumbs"];          

  echo '
            <img src="images/forsale/'.$img.'">
       ';           
}

mysqli_close( $link );
```

The code works, it will go to my database and get the result, however it only works with one image, the rest won't load unless its named the same.
I can't seem to figure out where Im going wrong with this. Please see attached my screenshots too to get an idea of what is happening.

Thanks for the help peeps =]

database:

[image: database]

Database Screenshot:

[image: Database Screenshot]

Website Screenshot:
[image: Website Screenshot]

Image not loading:

[image: Image not loading]

Comment: forgot to mention that there is a image called bedroom.jpg and bed.jpg in my images folder.

Comment: Caching issue? If you hover the link in console/web-inspector in the browser, does the `bed.jpg` show?

Comment: "...does not show.". Have you checked the HTML your code produces, and whether or not the images exist?

Comment: the inspector will say - failed to load

Comment: so I loaded each of the images first into dreamweaver using html, then deleted the html, now it seems to be working :S   so would this be a cache issue ?   new to php so not sure what Im doing to be honest ^^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it has something to do with caching.
Could you try to change the img src with a GET parameter.

```
   $propertyid = $row['propertyid'];
   echo '
        <img src="images/forsale/'.$img.'?id='.$propertyid.'">
    ';
```

Or try to show if it is retrieving the right data:

```
echo $img;
```

Comment: Thanks K Tromp, but echo $img;  will return the correct data from the database, its probably something stupid that I haven't noticed

Comment: eugh Im such an idiot, I didn't update my server folder to include the images -.-#

Thanks for the help everyone! =]

Comment: Lol but np could happen to anyone, still its weird that it showed the old image, but glad you figured it out